# Prolog- translating English to C

Tags: list, prolog, nlp, dcg

We have a relatively simple assignment that I understand in theory but I think I just don't quite understand Prolog's syntax enough to get that into code. Basically, we have a list of English notations that represent operations in C. They're stored as a list when they're passed to our Prolog program. For example:

```
add 4 to 3
```

is

```
[add, 4, to, 3]
```

We need to write a function that takes that list an returns the equivalent. So if I called

```
english2C([add,4,to,3], C).
C = 4+3
```

It would bind C to the result. So the data structure itself would be something like +(4(3)). We have a list of such English notation we have to translate, so it's a finite number. It's not like we have to account for all possibilities. There are also combinations, where they take two operations and combine them (with a comma in between)

```
english2C([add,3,to,5,',',then,subtract,7], C).
C = 3+5-7
```

I'm just somewhat confused as to how to start. I know I can take the very first element of the list and that will always be an operator (+,-,*, etc etc) and then I can just recursively go through the list looking for the operands. The problem there is for things that require order of operations, like "add 3 to 5 then multiply by 4", which should be represented as (3+5)*4 but if you just translate it directly you get 3+5*4.

Oh and we have to see if we can get it to run backwards (give it a C statement (3+5) and translate back to english (add 3 to 5)). That part I don't really have an idea for at all.

EDIT: There's a large enough permutations of possible English notations that I can't just pattern match everything. I get the idea that what I need to do is match the first operator with it's corresponding arithmetic symbol then find the operands. For a combinational statement, that would be the first part (so I would have 3+5) and then there would be a comma followed by the next statement. By the way, the combinational statements can be as long as they want, so it's not just two statements and I'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a reasonable small number of patterns, you could do:

```
english2C([add,X,to,Y], R) :- R is X+Y.
english2C([add,A,to,B,',',then,subtract,C], R) :- R is A+B-C.
```

**edit**

Those rules above *compute* the value. To translate, we can use DCG for matching, it's working 'backwards' as well.

```
english2C(In, R) :- phrase(toe(R), In, []).

toe(X+Y) --> [add,X,to,Y].
toe(X*Y) --> [multiply,X,by,Y].
toe(L-R) --> toe(L), [',',then,subtract,R].
```

test:

```
?- english2C(X,3+6).
X = [add, 3, to, 6].
```

**edit** sorry, I forgot a cut. With that added, I get

```
?- english2C([add,3,to,5,',',then,subtract,4],X).
X = 3+5-4.

?- english2C(L,3+5-4).
L = [add, 3, to, 5, ',', then, subtract, 4].
```

without, there is the loop after ;

```
?- english2C([add,3,to,5,',',then,subtract,4],X).
X = 3+5-4 ;
^CAction (h for help) ? goals
[698,875] toe(_G2096630, [add, 3, to, 5, ',', then, subtract, 4], _G2096652)
[698,874] toe('<garbage_collected>', '<garbage_collected>', _G2096652)
...
```

It's a single point change: do you prefer to find it yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not THAT small XD But the idea is right. Basically the idea I have is to match the first element with an operator then go down into the list to get the operands, but that would have to be recursive and I have to be able to separate the combinational statements.

Comment: Oh that's.....a lot simpler than what I was trying to do. And it works more reliably as well. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Oh, almost anyways. I have to tweak it a bit since it works for all cases where there is a rule defined, but if I use some random phrase that isn't defined in the rules (it should return no) there's a stack overflow error. But other than that, I think it works.

Comment: Oh, I see what it is. There are two times it crashes. If it gives me an answer and I don't accept it (type ';') it tries to redo the call but the answer from the previous call (3+5) is already stored and it goes into an infinite loop. But I don't think I can add a cut to stop it. Likewise if it doesn't find the phrase in the lists of rules, it goes into an infinite loop. There should be a way to just return no though.

Comment: Attempt to keep the code simpler than possible, mimic the syntax as far as you can. This could be a rather 'void' hint, because reducing the program to more essential terms can be difficult or impossible...

Comment: It seems it's just the implementation of phrase that causes this. When you attempted a phrase such as [add,3,to,5,',',then,subtract,4] it overflows because it first finds 3+5 and then goes into an infinite loop trying to get to the -4 part. I'll probably just have to figure out a way to implement it purely as a list of rules.

Comment: Oh man, ok lemme see if I can find it. I've been trying to put a cut somewhere to stop it from going into an infinite loop. The main problem is that I thought you couldn't put cuts when you were writing DCG rules. Is the cut somewhere else then?

Comment: Ok, sorry that I've been so much trouble. That problem seems to be solved by putting toe(L-R) --> toe(L), !, [',',then,subtract,R]. But what about if the user tries to put a phrase that doesn't exist in th ruleset? For example, they try [2, plus, 2], but such a rule isn't defined. Normally, prolog just returns 'no' to indicate that it wasn't found, but it seems like it goes into an infinite loop here. I don't think a cut will work here, since it never finds an answer to begin with (where as the other worked since the answer was found we just had to stop it there)

Comment: So in the end, while this was a lot of help and I think I can figure this out using DCGs, I don't think I can use phrase specifically because the way that toe(E) is called recursively, if I put cuts to stop the infinite looping, I can't combine more than two terms. For example, we need to be able to do [add,3,to,5,','then,subtract,4,',',then,subtract,1], basically we need to be able to append as many base rules together as we want. But when I try to move the cut to allow that, it looks like that causes an infinite loop in the above mentioned case.